# Base85 aka ASCII85 java projects

Tags: java, project, base85, ascii85

Does anyone know about any other than [com.idataconnect.lib.ascii85codec](http://java.net/projects/ascii85codec) java projects that do something like `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this project that seems to do the trick:
http://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html#recent

Following class encodes and decodes. Code reviews and suggestions are very welcome:

```
 import org.apache.pdfbox.io.ASCII85InputStream;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.io.ASCII85OutputStream;

 import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;



 public class Ascii85Coder {

 public static byte[] decodeAscii85StringToBytes(String ascii85) {
    ArrayList<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    ByteArrayInputStream in_byte = null;
    try {
        in_byte = new ByteArrayInputStream(ascii85.getBytes("ascii"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ASCII85InputStream in_ascii = new ASCII85InputStream(in_byte);
    try {
        int r ;
        while ((r = in_ascii.read()) != -1) {
            list.add((byte) r);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return bytes;
}


public static String encodeBytesToAscii85(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out_byte = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ASCII85OutputStream  out_ascii = new ASCII85OutputStream(out_byte);

    try {
        out_ascii.write(bytes);
        out_ascii.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String res = "";
    try {
        res = out_byte.toString("ascii");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
}
```

Comment: Since PDFbox is open source you can copy the code to your project so as not to burden your classpath with things you may not need.

Comment: Suggestion: Remove printStackTrace.  Either deal with the problem or re/throw an exception.

Comment: Note when copying open source source code into your project you still need to comply with the license of the copied code, e.g. give attribution, include copy of license etc.

Answer (score -1):

There's Ascii85 implementation on [java.net](http://java.net/projects/ascii85codec).

Comment: Well, isn't the link I provided above the same as the codec that you specified?

Comment: @Mat Banik, the link I gave points to the page already, what link are you referring to?